# Query performance rails comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making an instagram replica. I want to make a query that gets me all the users that liked a post. In summary a user as many posts, a post as many likes, and a user also has many likes. These are the solutions I came up with

```
def get_user_likes
    post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    #first solution
    @user_likes =  post.likes.map(&:users)
    #second solution
    @user_likes = User.includes(:likes).select(:username, :id, :profile_image).where(
        likes: {post_id: params[:post_id])})
end
```

I also want to select only a few columns (in which the first option does not allow me). In terms of performance which of the options is better? Is there any better option?

Thanks!!

Comment: The first solution will cause a n+1 query since you don't include 'users'. The second one is good but if you won't use the `Like` objects you can use `joins` instead `includes` so the Like objects won't loaded to the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment from Mehmet stated, the second solution is better.
I will extend the comment a little, the first solution is easy to understand but will call a query for each like in the map, these problems are commonly known as n+1 queries.

The second solution is way better, not exactly what you want here though. The includes will run a second query and is good to iterate over an object later.

The best solution is with a join, first because it will do one query less, and second because will return exactly what you, so just replace your includes with join and it is good to go:

```
def user_likes
  @user_likes = User.joins(:likes).select(:username, :id, :profile_image).where(likes: {post_id: params[:post_id])})
end
```

I could explore more but the answer would be a blog post and I can recommend a blog post for you:
https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2017/08/09/faster-rails-eliminating-n-plus-one-queries.html